# QGIS: It is possible to georeference a map that is only 1 meter square?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

Using the default CRS in QGIS `EPSG:4326`, it is possible to georeference a map of an area that's only 1 meter by 1 meter?

The picture below represents a track that can be built using approx. 15" foam segments.  I would like to create a `gpkg` that has a vectorized map of lane segments/boundaries, and a baseline path, that I can then use for motion planning and control algorithms.

A previous question here mentioned georeferencing, and having read the documentation, and watched a few videos, I've attempted it but without success.

Before going further down that path, I would like to confirm if it's possible to have a vectorized map of an area that's only 1 meter sqaured?

[image]

Comment: What/where are you trying to georeference this image/patches to? I.e. what are you trying to align this image with?

Comment: The idea is to create an API which uses data from the gpkg to return X,Y coordinates for lange segment polygons, and the baseline path.  

This way a robot can localize itself along the path; unfortunately using dead reckoning, but I can supplement that with lane detection from a front facing camera.

Since the track would be in my living room, I would use points on my street as a georeference

Comment: While it _might_ technically be possible (with lots and lots of control points), I don't think you will be successful using a global coordinate reference system to achieve (sub?)cm-scale accuracy. I also don't quite see why you'd need to do this, as opposed to creating your own local CRS (why does the CRS need to cover larger area than your living room?). If you were planning on using GPS to help the robot self-locate, you have to recognize that GPS itself will not allow this level of accuracy.